# How is charge confined to the region in which it is placed on a non-conductor?

Tags: electrostatics

"A charge placed on an insulator is confined to the region in which it was placed. An insulator has no charge carriers that are free to migrate within the boundaries of a body"

(Whelan & Hodgson, Pre-University Physics, 1971, p.268).

If a bunch of negative charge-carriers (electrons) are deposited (e.g. by rubbing with rabbit fur) on one end of an otherwise neutral teflon rod, then what stops them from moving apart from each other as a result of mutual electrostatic repulsion forces as per Coulomb's Law, either to other parts of the rod surface or away from the rod into the surrounding air or vacuum?

"Lack of charge carriers" is not a sufficient explanation; - why are charge carriers necessary? - why cannot the deposited electrons move of their own accord?, - something must be holding them to a particular place on the rod - what?

**Update**

According to [wikipedia: Triboelectric Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) the "placed" electrons actually jump from atoms in the donor (fur) to atoms in the receiver (teflon).  The [generic model of Wang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Electron_cloud_model.jpg) explains this as happening because the enforced close physical positions of suitable donor and receiver atoms results in electron cloud overlap which reduces the energy barrier allowing electrons to jump from suitable source atoms to suitable receiver atoms.

I cannot access the cited references (e.g. [Xi et al, 2018: "On the Electron‐Transfer Mechanism in the Contact‐Electrification Effect"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/adma.201706790) )but I guess that during separation of the donor and receiver materials (some, at least, of) the transferred electrons do not have suitable opportunity to make the jump back from their receiver atom to a donor atom. And presumably, following complete separation of the two materials, the donor material contains positively-ionised surface atoms and the receiver contains negatively-ionised surface atoms.

Comment: One needs energy to excite an electron from valence to conduction band. The band gap is too high for insulators. After filling up the valence band by adding more and more electrons, to enter into the conduction band- one needs energy.

Comment: @Syed Jaffri Are you implying that the deposited electrons become bound to (previously neutral) atoms in the (previously neutral) insulator.

Comment: I'm only saying that in conductors, the electrons are in energetic states, in conduction band, where they can easily move. So, if one add electrons to conductor, the initial electrons don't much hinder in the added electrons movement(as initial  electrons can easily move). But in insulator- electrons are bound and fixed. So, added electrons get hindered in movement.

Comment: @Syed Jaffri thanks. I found some stuff on triboelectric effect and added an update to my question.  It seems that electrons jump from some donor atoms to some receiver atoms resulting in ionisation of both atoms.

Comment: This goes to a sort of insufficiency in electronic band diagrams, no? The fairy tale is that you have these two bands, conduction and valence, separated by a huge gap: and since the valence band is completely filled there is no ability to generate net charge flow. But if this is true for say a glass rod, why can I rub it with fur and put charges on the surface in the first place? What band are those charges in, if not the conduction band -- you told me the valence band was full! The only way I can see the band diagram working is if new levels are being induced in the gap. Hm.

Comment: @CR Drost this is beyond my current understanding, but after reading wikiepdia I have added in my question reference to the recent work of Xi et al 2018. I cannot access the full article but the image in wikipedia of Wang (which I link to) may answer some of your questions :)